# Get custom fields from users table in global user object

Tags: 7, entities, users

I've altered users table and added two new fields directly using MySQL workbench

1. first_name
2. last_name

If we add new fields by config > people > site information > manage fields, it does not allow adding drop-down list. So, directly added using MySQL workbench.

Now I was able to alter user_register_form and added above two fields with validation.
At the time of creating new user, the values of first_name and last_name gets stored in users table.

Now, how to get those two fields when user logs in?

i've used below code to print user object

```
global $user;
$user_full = user_load($user->uid);
print_r($user_full);
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks !!

Comment: This is not the way to do it ! Use the [entity module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) to add field to the user object just like you add field to a content type. When you create your field tick the `"Display on user registration form."` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the [hook_user_load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_load/7) for this purpose

I have altered the user table with field "**fname**" , Now you can load this in user object with the help of **hook_user_load()** func.

```
function testing_custom_user_load($users) {
  foreach ($users as $record) {
     foreach ($users as $record) {

        $result = db_query("SELECT fname FROM {users} WHERE uid IN ($record->uid)")->fetchAssoc(); 

        $users[$record->uid]->extra =$result['fname'];
     }
  }

}
```

Just put this code snippet in any of your custom module file.

Comment: I want those fields in $user object, how it can be done and where should the above code placed ?

Comment: Answer updated, Please check.